# I have an trouble to analyse the C# code for the graphline

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I have C# code with a graphline which is line with many markers to be plotted using xy data. I am having trouble finding the x y data for the line fragments which is one of the markers in the line so I need to find the xy data for the line fragments.

Here is my XML data:

```
Starting XY = <MarkerNode x="3091" y="605" NodeID="1120" MasterEdge="0">
 ENDING XY <Junction x="3525" y="605" NodeID="1028">
<LineObject From="1120" To="1028" LineID="293" MasterEdge="2">
      <Track>true</Track>
      <EDir>0</EDir>
      <OrderedObjectList>
        <LineFragment ParentSegment="1032" Type="0" OffSetFromEdgeStart="645141" OffSetToEdgeEnd="471764" Length="86235" Gradient="0" Curve="0" SystemName="LF1032.1"/>
        <LineFragment ParentSegment="1032" Type="0" OffSetFromEdgeStart="731376" OffSetToEdgeEnd="385529" Length="86235" Gradient="0" Curve="0" SystemName="LF1032.2"/>
        <LineFragment ParentSegment="1032" Type="0" OffSetFromEdgeStart="817611" OffSetToEdgeEnd="299294" Length="86235" Gradient="0" Curve="0" SystemName="LF1032.3"/>
        <LineFragment ParentSegment="1032" Type="0" OffSetFromEdgeStart="903846" OffSetToEdgeEnd="213056" Length="86238" Gradient="0" Curve="0" SystemName="LF1032.4"/>
        <LineFragment ParentSegment="1033" Type="0" OffSetFromEdgeStart="990084" OffSetToEdgeEnd="154809" Length="58247" Gradient="0" Curve="0" SystemName="LF1033.1"/>
        <LineFragment ParentSegment="1033" Type="0" OffSetFromEdgeStart="1048331" OffSetToEdgeEnd="96561" Length="58248" Gradient="0" Curve="0" SystemName="LF1033.2"/>
        <LineFragment ParentSegment="1136" Type="0" OffSetFromEdgeStart="1106579" OffSetToEdgeEnd="0" Length="96561" Gradient="0" Curve="0" SystemName="LF1136"/>
      </OrderedObjectList>
    </LineObject>
```

Based on the XML, I have a starting X Y and ending X Y, and I have to map the xy to be plotted on the screen from the startxy and endxy in between there was the linefragments has been plotted but here I have length I don't know how to convert the length into Xy data for each linefragment.

Here is the C# code showing how they are doing it :

```
virtual protected void InitializeFragments(XSD.LineFragment[] fragmentlist, ATRGraph parent, XSD.Settings settings)
{
    GraphLineFragment newFragment = null;

    foreach (var node in fragmentlist)
    {
        newFragment = new GraphLineFragment(settings, this, node);

        if (fragmentsList.Count == 0)
        {
            newFragment.IsFirst = true;
        }

        fragmentsList.Add(newFragment);
        parent.AddFragment(newFragment);

        lineFullLen += newFragment.Length;
    }

    if (newFragment != null)
    {
        newFragment.IsLast = true;
    }
}

override public void UpdateObjectInView(Rectangle visibleLogicalArea)
{
    from.ObjectInView = visibleLogicalArea.Contains(from.X, from.Y);
    to.ObjectInView = visibleLogicalArea.Contains(to.X, to.Y);

    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(Math.Min(from.X, to.X), Math.Min(from.Y, to.Y), Math.Abs(from.X - to.X), Math.Abs(from.Y - to.Y));
    this.ObjectInView = visibleLogicalArea.Contains(bounds) ||
                        visibleLogicalArea.IntersectsWith(bounds) ||
                        from.ObjectInView || to.ObjectInView; 
}

protected virtual void DrawFragmentsTo(bool bTrainsLayer, Graphics g, float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, bool drawFragmentNames)
{
    if (trainsOnObject.Count > 0)
    {
        //Logger.log.DebugFormat("[GraphLine.DrawFragmentsTo] (x1,y1):({0},{1}); (x2,y2):({2},{3})", x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }

    int accum_len = 0;

    float dx = x2 - x1, dy = y2 - y1;
    float startX = x1;
    float startY = y1;

    linepath = new GraphicsPath();

    foreach (GraphLineFragment fragment in fragmentsList)
    {
        accum_len += fragment.Length;

        //use fragment lengths:
        float rlen = ((float)accum_len) / (float)lineFullLen;

        float lx = x1 + dx * rlen;
        float ly = y1 + dy * rlen;

        if (fragment.Length > 0)
        {
            if (bezierNode != null && !ParentGraph.UseGisCoordinates)
            {
                lx = bezier(x1, ParentGraph.TransFormX(bezierNode.FloatX), ParentGraph.TransFormX(bezierNode.FloatX), x2, rlen);
                ly = bezier(y1, ParentGraph.TransFormY(bezierNode.FloatY), ParentGraph.TransFormY(bezierNode.FloatY), y2, rlen);
            }

            float ox = dy;
            float oy = dx;
            float dist = (float)Math.Sqrt((double)(ox * ox + oy * oy));

            if (dist > 0)
            {
                ox /= dist * .2f;//fixme:hardcoded
                oy /= dist * .2f;
            }

            //int iSR = 0;

            fragment.FromX = startX;
            fragment.FromY = startY;
            fragment.ToX = lx;
            fragment.ToY = ly;
            fragment.DelimitorFromX = lx + ox;
            fragment.DelimitorFromY = ly - oy;
            fragment.DelimitorToX = lx - ox;
            fragment.DelimitorToY = ly + oy;

            fragment.DrawTo(g, bTrainsLayer, drawFragmentNames);
            linepath.AddLine(fragment.FromX, fragment.FromY, fragment.ToX, fragment.ToY);
        }

        startX = lx;
        startY = ly;
    }
}

private void DrawJunctionLine(Graphics g, GraphNode from, GraphNode to, int length)
{
    float ffX = ParentGraph.TransFormX(from.FloatX);
    float ffY = ParentGraph.TransFormY(from.FloatY);
    float ftX = ParentGraph.TransFormX(to.FloatX);
    float ftY = ParentGraph.TransFormY(to.FloatY);

    float dX = ftX - ffX;
    float dY = ftY - ffY;

    double len = Math.Sqrt(dX * dX + dY * dY);

    // Normalize deltas
    double normX = len > 0 ? dX / len : 0;
    double normY = len > 0 ? dY / len : 0;

    // Make sure that actual length won't be longer than half of the edge
    length = ParentGraph.TransFormLength(length);
    // length = Math.Min((int)len/3, length);

    double endX = ffX + normX * (length);
    double endY = ffY + normY * (length);

    // Do not overdraw trainpath with junction line
    if (currentPathColorer == null)
        g.DrawLine(JunctionLinePen, ffX, ffY, (int)endX, (int)endY);
}

public void DrawJunctionLine(Graphics g, GraphJunction junction)
{
    if (junction == from)
    {
        DrawJunctionLine(g, from, bezierNode != null ? bezierNode : to, ParentGraph.Settings.Junction.ConnectedLineLength); // Circle size div by 2, to get radius
    }

    if (junction == to)
    {
        DrawJunctionLine(g, to, bezierNode != null ? bezierNode : from, ParentGraph.Settings.Junction.ConnectedLineLength); // Circle size div by 2, to get radius
    }
}

// Calculate percentual point in bezier curve
private float bezier(float p0, float p1, float p2, float p3, float t)
{
    return (1 - t) * (1 - t) * (1 - t) * p0 + 3 * (1 - t) * (1 - t) * t * p1 + 3 * (1 - t) * t * t * p2 + t * t * t * p3;
}

ePhysicalEdgeDir currentpathDirectionInfo;

override public void SetTrainPathOfTrain(IPathColorer pathColorerInstance, ePhysicalEdgeDir directionInfo,ushort eventFlags)
{
    currentPathColorer = pathColorerInstance;
    currentpathDirectionInfo = directionInfo;

    foreach (GraphLineFragment fragment in fragmentsList)
    {
        fragment.SetTrainPathOfTrain(pathColorerInstance, directionInfo, eventFlags);
    }
}

override public IPathColorer GetTrainPathOfTrainParent()
{
    return currentPathColorer;
}

public GraphLineFragment NearestFragment(Point p)
{
    PointF closest;
    double minDist = Double.MaxValue;
    GraphLineFragment closestFragment = null;

    foreach (GraphLineFragment fragment in fragmentsList)
    {
        double dist = MathHelper.FindDistanceToSegment(p, new Point((int)fragment.FromX, (int)fragment.FromY), new Point((int)fragment.ToX, (int)fragment.ToY), out closest);

        if (minDist > dist)
        {
            minDist = dist;
            closestFragment = fragment;
        }
    }

    return closestFragment;
}
```

This is the C# code - I need help to identify the linefragment Xy data help me with the mathematical logic to identify this?

Comment: Is your question about getting XY for start- and end-point of each line in the xml-file? I think that's what these offset-values are for, so you need to read these. No idea about the coordinates coordonate-system, though